# yum not working on EC2 Red Hat instance: Cannot retrieve repository metadata

Tags: amazon-ec2, redhat, yum

For some reason yum has stopped working in my Amazon EC2 instance, located in the EU West sector. There seems to be something wrong with the path of the repo metadata, is this correct? I would be very grateful for any help, as my experience in this field is somewhat limited.

cat /etc/redhat-release:

```
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.2 (Santiago)
```

yum repolist:

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
https://rhui2-cds01.eu-west-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 401"
Trying other mirror.
https://rhui2-cds02.eu-west-1.aws.ce.redhat.com/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 401"
Trying other mirror.
repo id                                                                     repo name                                                                                       status
rhui-eu-west-1-client-config-server-6                                       Red Hat Update Infrastructure 2.0 Client Configuration Server 6                                 0
rhui-eu-west-1-rhel-server-releases                                         Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6 (RPMs)                                                        0
rhui-eu-west-1-rhel-server-releases-optional                                Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 6 Optional (RPMs)                                               0
repolist: 0
```

yum update: (I needed to remove the base URLs below because of ServerFault's restrictions for new users)

```
Loaded plugins: amazon-id, rhui-lb, security
[same as base url 1 above]/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 401"
Trying other mirror.
[same as base url 2 above]/pulp/repos//rhui-client-config/rhel/server/6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] PYCURL ERROR 22 - "The requested URL returned error: 401"
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: rhui-eu-west-1-client-config-server-6. Please verify its path and try again
```

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=389303

It appears that you have the same problem. The issue on AWS forum is not resolved yet but I hope it will aid your understanding of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Trying running:

```
   yum clean all

   rhn_check -vv
```

Answer (score -1):

Likely the same problem as in this link which also includes a fix (posting by Mostafa re billingProducts set to null):
   https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=128658

Comment: If you believe this forum post has a solution in it, please copy at least the essence of the solution into your answer. We generally don't like link-only answers to questions here.

Answer (score -2):

you have to add an inbound rule for HTTPS in your security group then it will work

Comment: This is typically not necessary if you haven't mucked with the defaults.